# Find the value of function with given conditions

Tags: functions, polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be a fifth degree polynomial with leading coefficient unity.

If $f(1)=5, f(2)=4, f(3)=3, f(4)=2 , f(5)=1$  find $f(6)$

I know I can solve this by assuming a polynomial equation and then finding the coefficients of every term and finding the value of $f(6)$ but I wanted to know if there is any other method of solving this problem. Any hints to solve this kind of problem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $g(x) = f(x) - (6 - x)$. It is clear that $g(x) = 0$ for $x \in \{1, \ldots, 5\}$.
Moreover, $g$ is also a degree $5$ polynomial with leading coefficient unity. Thus, we may factorise it as
$$f(x) - (6 - x) = g(x) = (x - 1)\cdots(x - 5).$$

Subsituting $x = 6$ in the above gives
$$f(6) = 5! = 120.$$